# AngularJS Custom Service is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a simple service I created:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.service('UserService', function() {

this.user = {firstName:"",middleName:"",lastName:"",email:"",dob:""};
this.addUser = function (user) {
  users.push(user);
}
this.displayUser = function (user) {
  this.user = user;
}
});
```

This is the controller where I want to use the service:

```
app.controller('DisplayUserController', ['$scope','UserService', 
function($scope, UserService) {

$scope.user = UserService.user;

}]);
```

This is the HTML where I am passing the user object to user directive:

```
<div ng-controller="DisplayUserController">
 <div>{{user.firstName}}</div>
 <div>{{user.middleName}}</div>
 <div>{{user.lastName}}</div>
</div>
```

Why am I getting "Unknown provider: userProvider <- user" error? Please help.

Comment: Yes, the problem started when I created service.

Comment: what is `users`? Is not defined anywhere. Create a [mcve] demo in plunker that reproduces problem

Comment: That is a global array, used by other controllers

Comment: `<user ng-model="user"></user>` you are using `user` directive in the HTML template without defining it.

Comment: Ignore user directive, that is working fine. Please let me know whats wrong in the service declaration and usage

Comment: Removed the user directive

Comment: Your service needs to return 'something', add `return this;` to the service.

Comment: @Michael, please see this snippet http://jsbin.com/suxed/1/edit?html,js,output. The service does not return anything and is working fine.

Comment: @JVM looks completely fine to me, and verified there are no errors in [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/avexAybyaoCwtyUCLuKQ?p=preview)

Comment: @JVM You're right sorry.   The only other thing I can think of is you didn't include the `ngRoute` package.  Try it like @user2341963 showed and see if that works.

Comment: I created a plunker for this, please take a look [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/JRW0UDpse0RT304inOID?p=preview) and let me know whats wrong in it.

Comment: @Hoyen, the code is working when I don't use Routes i.e. all content is present on the page, take a look here: http://jsbin.com/vayigovota/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @charlietfl - added a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JRW0UDpse0RT304inOID?p=preview), can you take a look

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the ngModel to your directive:

```
.directive('user', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      'user': '=ngModel'
    },
    templateUrl:'display-single-user.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
        var user = $scope.user;
        $scope.firstName = user.firstName;
        $scope.middleName = user.middleName;
        $scope.lastName = user.lastName;
        $scope.email = user.email;
        $scope.dob = user.dob;
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in my directive, I was using internal controller that also needed the UserService therefore added it as a dependency and it started working. Now, please let me know if this is a correct practice to follow.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('user', ['UserService', function() {
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl:'templates/display-single-user.html',
     controller: function($scope, UserService) {

         $scope.firstName = UserService.user.firstName;
         $scope.middleName = UserService.user.middleName;
         $scope.lastName = UserService.user.lastName;
         $scope.email = UserService.user.email;
         $scope.dob = UserService.user.dob;
     }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Unless there's a lot more complexity that you're not showing, I think a better approach might be to inject the UserService into the controller(s) and pass the user to the directive using the directive's scope option, [explained here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Based on your example, I don't think you need the controller function in your directive to accomplish what it looks like you're intending.